# Does one have to complete a message after dead-lettering it in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, dead-letter

When we use an Azure Service Bus queue in `PeekLock` mode, an error occurs and we call [ServiceBusReceiver.DeadLetterMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.deadlettermessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) explicitly, do we then also have to call [ServiceBusReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.completemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) afterwards in order to settle the message? Or is the message already settled automatically by dead-lettering it?

Comment: *Or is the message already settled automatically by dead-lettering it?* Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message will be placed in the dead letter queue just by calling DeadLetterMessageAsync on it. If you later want to remove the message from the dead letter queue then you need to actually lock it and call CompleteMessageAsync on it (if using Peek Lock mode).